# Не могу понять, когда ставится окончание -йся или -еся?

Tags: грамматика

Например: в слове *делающийся*. Знаю что -йся, но как разграничить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По роду существительного.

Он - какой? - делающи**й**ся.

*Клоун, делающийся из картона и клея, смотрится неплохо, но - на один раз.*

Она - какая? - делающа**я**ся.

*Простыня, делающаяся из ацетатного шелка, обычно не доживает до первой стирки.*

Оно - какое? - делающе**е**ся.

*Задание, делающееся наспех, зачастую даёт печальный результат.*